# how to get arrays from refs with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My problem is that when I `find() and print` my entries, arrays don't show off. Wich is a problem because I need to send for my API.

Here the result I get :

```
    {
      "_id": "576287e5a3536e670a39f3f2",
      "__v": 0,
      "products": [],
      "name": "SISI CEST ICI"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5762897e3032fe7c0a1d2408",
      "__v": 0,
      "products": [],
      "name": "hElo la mif"
    }
```

Here is how i get this result :

```
  var response = {};
  mongoose.cat.find({},function(err,data){
   console.log(data);
 // Mongo command to fetch all data from collection.
     if(err) {
         response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
     } else {
         response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
     }
     res.json(response);
 });
```

The model looks like this :

```
var category = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    products: [ {type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Product'} ]
});

var product = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    price: { type: Number, default: '' }
});

var restoModel = mongoose.model('Resto', resto);
var MenuModel = mongoose.model('Menu', menu);
var CategoryModel = mongoose.model('Category', category);
var ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product', product);



module.exports = {
  resto: restoModel,
  menu: MenuModel,
  cat: CategoryModel,
  product: ProductModel
}
```

Whereas in my database, the fields products are not empty, a screen can show that :

[image: what i want to show]

So my question is : How do I access the data inside my arrays of products ? because I need them to send it back.

I have tried a `"Populate query"` but it didn't gave anything.

My question is, how can Have a in a Json format all the data from my main category ?

Answer (score 0):

**//category.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    products: [{productID: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref :      'Product'}}]
});

module.Category = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

**//product.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    price: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

module.Product = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

**//some file**

```
var Product = require('./Product').Product,
    Category = require('./Category').Category;

var product = new Product({
    name: "Some name",
    price: 100
});

product.save(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});


*//creating*
var category = new Category({
    name: "Some name",
    products: [{
         productID: product._id
    },{
.....///and so on.....
    }]
});

*//saving*
category.save(function(error) {
    if (!error) {
        Category.find({})
            .populate('products.productID')
            .exec(function(error, cats) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(cats, null, "\t"))
            })
    }
});
```

i hope it helps you.

Comment: the Category.find.populate shows off the same data than Category.find()